# Implementing simple modules or extensions for axis2 as an eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, module, apache-axis

I wish to setup an eclipse project for implementing a simple module but not a service for axis. I wonder if there're any templates I could use?

Secondly, I would like to ask if there are any information sources such as links around on how to build complex Axis2 applications in eclipse mainly focusing on module building as well

I appreciate your hints.
Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I could come along with this issue with my own solution:

Using an customized build.xml based on axis2 module builds I am able to build a module project in Eclipse using ant. I trigger this via key shortcut.

The build.xml has an deploy.module target that puts the module back to the axis2 $HOME/repository folder. Running there ant build.xml will deploy axis2 at whole as an war-file (EAR) the module containing there within to be ready to deploy in a container such as jboss.

The eclipse project is based on common java project (no dynamic web project) containing the $AXIS2/lib in CLASSPATH.

Since Jboss supports hot deployment on update, you can run jboss in a terminal or withing eclipse. I customized the latter build.xml to support easy jboss deployment.

This is a good solution for me.